# ScreenShot Tutorial Creator software

Tags: windows-7, screen-capture

I'm looking out for a software which can create tutorials from screen shots and output them to html at the end of it.

I should be able to add the text while the screen shot is taken though the text should ideally not be published on the screen shot but to the html page that it outputs at end.

With capabilities to capture active windows / full screen / custom shots.

I currently use snagit to do the same but its a long tedious process to stitch the whole thing together at the end. Also I would like to publish the same to a blog engine so if the pictures could be uploaded to a location I specify would make it even more convenient, and the links outputted automatically so that it can be included in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an amazing paid application to do the same after comprehensive searching [here's a link to the website](http://www.bluemangolearning.com/screensteps/) if anyone's interested.